# How to get the instances of the WebApplicationContext and DispatcherServlet in the spring-web-mvc at the runtime of an spring web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i want to get the instance of the WebApplicationContext and the DispatcherServlet instance in the function under the controller class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spring 2.5, you can get a reference to `WebApplicationContext` using `@Autowired` annotation:

```
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

You can also obtain a reference of `ApplicationContext` by implementing [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) interface :

```
public class YourController implements ApplicationContextAware {
ApplicationContext applicationContext;
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}
...
}
```

But I don't think there is way to get a reference to the `DispatcherServlet` instance or to an instance of any Servlet present in your application. Earlier there was a way to obtain it using [ServletContext.getServlet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServlet%28java.lang.String%29), which is deprecated now.